# Proving that $L_{-1}v=0$ implies $v\in V_0$ in a vertex operator algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

The discussion of the actual problem is labelled in bold after the notoriously long definition of vertex operator algebra is given for the sake of completeness (Note: "fields" and "locality" are not relevant for this exercise, as far as I can tell). (The definition of vertex algebra is taken from *Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves* by Frankel and Ben-Zvi, and the conditions for a vertex operator algebra as well as the exercise are from the notes "Vertex operators and modular forms" by Mason and Tuite.)

**Definition of vertex algebra.** A vertex algebra consists of:

$\bullet$ (space of states) a vector space $V$;

$\bullet$ (vacuum vector) a vector $|0\rangle\in V$;

$\bullet$ (translation operator) a linear operator $T:V\to V$;

$\bullet$ (vertex operators) a linear operation $$Y(\cdot,v):V\to \text{End}V[[z^{\pm 1}]];$$ taking each $A\in V$ to a field $$Y(A,z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} A_{(n)}z^{-n-1}$$ acting on $V$.

These data are subject to the axioms

$\bullet$ (vacuum axiom) $Y(|0\rangle,z)=\text{Id}V$. Furthermore, for any $A\in V$ we have $$Y(A,z)|0\rangle\in V[[z]],$$ so that $Y(A,z)|0\rangle$ has a well-defined value at $z=0$, and $$Y(A,z)|0\rangle|_{z=0}=A.$$

$\bullet$ (translation axiom) For any $A\in V$, $$[T,Y(A,z)]=\partial_z Y(A,z)$$ and $T|0\rangle=0$.

$\bullet$ (locality axiom) All fields $Y(A,z)$ are local with respect to each other.

A vertex algebra is called a **vertex operator algebra** if $V=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} V_n$, and $V$ has a distinguished vector $\omega$ called the conformal vector such that $Y(\omega,z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} L_n z^{-n-2}$, where the $L_n$ satisfy the Virasoro relation

$$[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n}+\frac{m^3-m}{12}c\text{Id}_V.$$

We also have that $V_n=\{v\in V:L_0v=nv\}$, dim$V_n=0$ for $n<<0$, and $Y(L_{-1}v,z)=\partial Y(v,z)$, i.e. $T=L_{-1}$.

**Facts from previous exercises.** We know that $Y(|0\rangle,z)=\text{Id}$, $|0\rangle\in V_0$, $\omega\in V_2$, $L_n |0\rangle =0$ for $n\geq -1$, and $(L_{-1}v)_n=-n v_{n-1}$.

**The problem.**

To show that $L_{-1}v=0$ implies that $v\in V_0$, I started by thinking of how one can use this data to generate expressions that relate $L_0v$ and $L_{-1}v$, such as

$$[L_1,L_{-1}]v=2L_0v=L_1(L_{-1}v)-L_{-1}(L_1v)=-L_{-1}(L_1v)$$ and $$[L_0,L_{-1}]v=L_{-1}v=0=L_0(L_{-1}v)-L_{-1}(L_0v)=-L_{-1}(L_0v).$$ The first expression doesn't seem to help since I can't see how to find/use the value of $L_1v$, and I don't see how the second expression could imply that $L_0v=0$, since if $v\in V_1$ for example we still have $L_{-1}(L_0v)=L_{-1}v=0$. Further, I can't see how any of the other data might apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've adapted the proof from Lepowsky and Li's *Introduction to Vertex Operator Algebras and Their Representations*. They prove a more general result, and we need not refer to the concepts of 'centralizer' or 'vertex operator subalgebra' to establish our result, namely that $L_{-1}v=0$ implies $v\in V_0$, i.e. $L_0v=0$.

The proof uses the commutator identity $$[u_m,v_n]=\sum_{i\geq 0} {m\choose i} (u_iv)_{m+n-i},$$ which I didn't include in the original post since (1) I didn't think it was relevant and (2) there are several other identities (the Jacobi identity and the associator and skew-symmetry identities), and if I included all of these my post would have been a giant wall of definitions. Lesson learned that I should have been more skeptical of my intuition.

First, we prove the useful fact from Remark 3.2.4 (more or less exactly as in the book) that for $u,v\in V$, $[Y(u,z_1),Y(v,z_2)]=0$ if and only if $u_nv=0$ for $n\geq 0$.

If $[Y(u,z_1),Y(v,z_2)]=0$, then $$\sum_{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}}[u_m,v_n]z_1^{-m-1}z_2^{-n-1}=0,$$ therefore $[u_m,v_n]=0\Rightarrow u_mv_n=v_nu_m$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. By the creativity axiom, $v=v_{-1}|0\rangle$ and $u_n|0\rangle=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, so for all $n\geq 0$ we have $$u_nv=u_nv_{-1}|0\rangle=v_{-1}u_n|0\rangle=0.$$ On the other hand, if we assume $u_nv=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, it follows immediately from the commutator identity that $[u_m,v_n]=0$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$. This completes the proof.

Now to the original problem. I showed in my other answer that $L_{-1}v=0$ implies that $Y(v,z)=v_{-1}$. Hence $v_n=0$ for $n\geq 0$, so for any $u\in V$ we have $v_nu=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. Remark 3.2.4 implies $Y(v,z)$ commutes with all other fields, i.e. for all $u\in V$ we have $[Y(v,z_1),Y(u,z_2)]=0$. This clearly implies that $[Y(u,z_2),Y(v,z_1)]=0$, hence $u_nv=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. This is true in particular for $u=\omega$; since $\omega_n=L_{n-1}$, for all $n\geq 0$ we have $$\omega_nv=L_{n-1}v=0,$$ so it follows that $L_{-1}v=L_0v=0$. Thus, $v\in V_0$.

Answer (score 0):

No solution yet, but a seemingly more promising approach than guesswork with the Virasoro bracket.

Another way of stating the problem is that $\ker L_{-1}\subseteq \ker L_0$, so perhaps one has to consider how these operators act on all of $V$ first.

We already know how $L_0$ acts on $V$: it acts as a map $V_k\to V_k$ on the homogeneous spaces, sending $v\mapsto kv$. $\ker L_0=V_0$ by definition.

We don't immediately know how $L_{-1}$ acts on vectors besides the vacuum, but we do know that it acts as a partial derivative on fields: $Y(L_{-1}v,z)=\partial_z Y(v,z)$. By the vacuum axiom, $$Y(L_{-1}v,z)|0\rangle|_{z=0}=L_{-1}v=\partial_zY(v,z)|0\rangle|_{z=0}=v_{-2}|0\rangle.$$ So for all $v\in V$, $L_{-1}v=v_{-2}|0\rangle.$ So $\ker L_{-1}=\{v\in V: v_{-2}|0\rangle=0\}.$

An important fact I forgot to mention (since I failed to see that it is relevant) is the injectivity of the state-field correspondence $v\mapsto Y(v,z)$. It follows from this that if $L_{-1}v=0$, then $Y(L_{-1}v,z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} 0_n z^{-n-1}$, where $0_n$ is the zero endomorphism for all $n$. Hence $0_n=(L_{-1}v)_n=-nv_{n-1}$ for all $n$, so in particular $v_n|0\rangle=0$ for all $n\leq -2$. It follows that $Y(v,z)|0\rangle=v.$ An arbitrary $u\in V$ satisfies $Y(u,z)|0\rangle=u+O(z)$, so perhaps this is strong enough to show that $v\in V_0$ already; I still don't quite see it yet.

**Edit.** I consulted Lepowski and Li's *Introduction to Vertex Operator Algebras and Their Representations*, and Proposition 3.11.2 gives a proof that $\ker L_{-1}\subset \ker L_0$ by defining the centralizer $C_V(U)$ of a vertex operator subalgebra $U$ of $V$ and showing that $C_V(U)$ is independent of $U$ and that $$C_V(U)=\ker L_{-1} \subset V_0=\ker L_0.$$ I am still curious if there is a simpler proof of this without referencing centralizers or vertex operator subalgebras, since this exercise came from the notes http://library.msri.org/books/Book57/files/40mason.pdf which did not define or use these concepts (at least not prior to the exercise, Exercise 2.28). I will see if I can adapt the argument from the book of Lepowski and Li in the meantime.